# Icons next to tags, like Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

On stack overflow they have icons next to some tags (see for example: [google-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension)). Blender has *a lot* of icons that a **very applicable** it has an icon for these tags to name a few:

[mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesh)
[modifiers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modifiers)
[armature](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armature)
[simulation-tags](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation-tags)
[rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendering)
[texturing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texturing)

Comment: This could be useful for helping users tag questions to an extent but I don't think that's the purpose and seems purely cosmetic on this site at least. Don't see much of a reason for it here really.

Comment: @iKlsR True, but still worth a shot right?

Comment: Could be used for the major panels (node editor) etc and external applications, can probably mention it when the site design is going up but highly unlikely to happen.

Comment: So should I add it to the thread?

Answer (score 5):

Those are [**sponsored tags**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sponsored-tags?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) and they are only available the owner of the name or trademark associated with the tag name.

Comment: So what happens if nobody owns a trademark, and we aren't attaching a logo, just software relevant icon?

Comment: Tag sponsorships are very limited, and it's not just to put an icon on the tag, it also implies that the company is supporting the site and maintaining the tag wiki, etc. We're not likely to start adding pictures to the tags outside this limited use case or it's going to start looking cluttered and distracting. Read some of the posts I linked above.